# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending nsinteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I'm pushing to another `WKInterfaceController` when a row is selected but I can't seem to pass the `rowIndex` as context for my new controller which I would like to do.

```
// Push to next controller and pass rowIndex as context
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    [self pushControllerWithName:(NSString *)@"ZoomPokeController"
                         context:rowIndex];
}
```

This code gives the error

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending NSInteger: implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC.

I can change my `context` to nil and the build succeeds but of course then I have no context. I've taken a look at the class documentation which has helped me a lot so far and similar questions on stackoverflow but I'm stuck not knowing how to write this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: in your method `[self pushControllerWithName:(NSString *)@"ZoomPokeController" context: rowIndex]` what is data type of context?

Comment: @Mr. Slowpoke can share the signature of pushControllerWithName selector?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.  No link to WKInterfacetable.  No info on what the context is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

```
"implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC."
```

Clearly says that you are passing `NSInteger` as a parameter where as method it suppose to be `id`.

In below line second parameter required `id` object.

```
[self pushControllerWithName:(NSString *)@"ZoomPokeController" context: rowIndex];
```

With the help of @fabian789, It is clear now that in  **[WKInterfaceController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/pushControllerWithName:context:)**

that method required `id` object as second parameter.

[image]

To pass an integer there, you can convert your `NSInteger` to an `NSNumber` and pass in a second parameter.

```
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSNumber *rowValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rowIndex];
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"ZoomPokeController" context: rowValue];
}
```

You can then in the target controller get the row index by calling `integerValue` on the context.

Comment: Yes! This did the trick, thanks very much. I NSLog'd my context in the new interface controller and got the values expected. Yay.

Comment: FYI `-pushControllerWithName:context:` is a method of `WKInterfaceController` and can not be changed. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/pushControllerWithName:context:).

Comment: I updated your answer, hope you don't mind!

Comment: Sure any time. Its appreciating.

Comment: Rashad provided the same solution 3 hours ago and the OP said it didn't work, so how is it that this answer is suddenly acceptable?

Comment: @Droppy: I don't know about OP's intention and what his getting. It's not in my hand.

Comment: How to access rowValue in ZoomPokeController ?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending wrong parameter type. Cast the `rowIndex` to `int` Try this:

```
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex: (NSInteger) rowIndex {

    NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: rowIndex]
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"ZoomPokeController" context: val];
}
```

Hope this help... :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. replacing my code with this but I still get two errors with that one. Implicit conversion of int to id is disallowed with ARC and incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'. If I scroll up to - (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context { and switch (id) to (int) or (NSInteger) I also get an error. I may have found somebody else's code to use as an example at https://github.com/leiyong316/AppleWatchDemo/blob/master/TestWatch%20WatchKit%20Extension/InterfaceController.m so I'll try studying that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Error clearly States what you are doing wrong, You are Sending an NSInteger type to only an integer, try declaring the context parameter as an `NSInteger` or use it like this,

```
[self pushControllerWithName:(NSString *)@"ZoomPokeController" context: (int)rowIndex];
```

but the earlier method is more effective